# cannot uninstall mysql for visual studio 1.2.7 in windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I am unable to uninstall mysql for visual studio 1.2.7 in windows 8.1.  I have used VS community 2017 previously. Recently, I have installed VS professional 2017 after uninstalling vs community 2017. I tried to connect to my wamp server from VS professional 2017, it shows error.

So, I tried to uninstall my connector and mysql for visual studio. Whenever, I tried to uninstall mysql for visual studio, it shows the error,

> "Fatal error during installation". unInstallation action roll-backed.

I have used revo-uninstaller to uninstall the mysql for visual studio. No use. Still the error persists.

Thanks in advance